# ESXi NIC in promiscous mode

Tags: esxi, esxi5.5

I have configured an esxi host on a Hyper-V, but am not able to ping out or into the ESXI host. I have followed all practices regarding setting up a Legacy adapter, and turned off firewall. I have read and reviewed a lot of posts and many seem to be pointing at enabling promiscuous mode on the ESXi NIC.

The unfortunate thing is, all methods (or all of the ones I had found) redirects to VMware's site on how to do this. Big issue with me, I cannot connect into or out from the ESXi host, which means that vCenter does not work. Come on VMware, really?

In any case, I need the command line steps from within the ESXi shell, if it is even possible to do so. does anyone know how to turn on Promiscous mode without vCenter, or vSpere?

Comment: You should be able to directly connect to the ESXi host with VSphere.  Since you are using 5.5 the desktop client works nicely in that configuration with root.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I am unable to connect to the esxi Host from another machine. I can only connect directly to it, and go into the shell. Unless, that is, Vsphere has another way to communicate to the host. Remember this is hosted on a Hyper-V.